# How to glue a function argument to .names in dplyr's across function?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyeval

I am trying to name the output of an `across` function using both `{col}` and one of the function arguments in

```
library(tidyverse)

mean_by <- function(data, by, var, prefix = "avg") {
  data %>% 
    group_by({{ by }}) %>% 
    summarise(across({{ var }}, mean, .names = "{prefix}_{col}"))
}
```

However, when testing on `iris %>% mean_by(Species, Sepal.Width)`, I get the error that object 'prefix' cannot be found. The glue syntax in `.names` looks okay to me so I assume this is a scoping issue? Can the `.names` argument only access what has been passed to `across`?

Comment: Can you post a feature request on github please? This is possibly something that should work.

Answer (score 3):

I believe `.names` in `across` only allow references to `{col}` and `{fn}` inside `across`, but you can try pasting your `prefix`:

```r
> library(tidyverse)
> mean_by <- function(data, by, var, prefix = "avg") {
  data %>% 
    group_by({{ by }}) %>% 
    summarise(across({{ var }}, mean, .names = paste0(prefix,"_{col}")))
 }
> iris %>% mean_by(Species, Sepal.Width)
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species    avg_Sepal.Width
  <fct>                <dbl>
1 setosa                3.43
2 versicolor            2.77
3 virginica             2.97
```