# How to use string manipulation functions inside .names argument in dplyr::across

Tags: r, dplyr, across, r-glue

Though I tried to search whether it is duplicate, but I cannot find similar question. (though a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63151985/how-to-glue-a-function-argument-to-names-in-dplyrs-across-function) one is there, but that is somewhat different from my requirement)

My question is that whether we can use string manipulation function such `substr` or `stringr::str_remove` inside `.names` argument of `dplyr::across`.  As a reproducible example consider this

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with('Sepal'), mean, .names = '{.col}_mean'))

  Sepal.Length_mean Sepal.Width_mean
1          5.843333         3.057333
```

Now my problem is that I want to rename output columns say `str_remove(.col, 'Sepal')` so that my output column names are just `Length.mean` and `Width.mean` .  Why I am asking because, the [description](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) of this argument states that

> .names
> A glue specification that describes how to name the output columns. This can use {.col} to stand for the selected column name, and {.fn} to stand for the name of the function being applied. The default (NULL) is equivalent to "{.col}" for the single function case and "{.col}_{.fn}" for the case where a list is used for .fns.

I have tried many possibilities including the following, but none of these work

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
iris %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with('Sepal'), mean, 
                   .names = glue('{xx}_mean', xx = str_remove(.col, 'Sepal'))))

Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..1`.
x argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)
i Input `..1` is `(function (.cols = everything(), .fns = NULL, ..., .names = NULL) ...`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.


#OR
iris %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with('Sepal'), mean, 
                   .names = glue('{xx}_mean', xx = str_remove(glue('{.col}'), 'Sepal'))))
```

I know that this can be solved by adding another step using `rename_with` so I am not looking after that answer.

Comment: You can use functions inside a glue string, such as `.names = '{str_remove(.col, "^[A-Za-z]+")}_mean'`, but it seems like this has limitations when it gets parsed

Comment: O yes!  Can you please post that as answer, I'll be happy to accept that. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works, but with probably a few caveats. You can use functions inside a glue specification, so you could clean up the strings that way. However, when I tried escaping the `"."`, I got an error, which I assume has something to do with how `across` parses the string. If you need something more dynamic, you might want to dig into the source code at that point.

In order to use the `{.fn}` helper, at least in conjunction with creating the glue string on the fly like this, the function needs a name; otherwise you get a number for the function's index in the `.fns` argument. I tested this out with a second function and using `lst` for automatic naming.

```r
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with('Sepal'), .fns = lst(mean, max), 
                   .names = '{stringr::str_remove(.col, "^[A-Za-z]+.")}_{.fn}'))
#>   Length_mean Length_max Width_mean Width_max
#> 1    5.843333        7.9   3.057333       4.4
```

Comment: `summarise(across(starts_with("Sepal"), mean, .names = 'mean_{str_remove(.col, "Sepal.")}'))` works in my case.  Thanks :)